# get data from json url in jquery div section

Tags: jquery, json

I have a json URL and i need to get data's json url in my section div like that

[Desired result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akBgw.png)

I need to know too how can I get all countries that start with C and get all that data's in the section with letter C 
same thing for D etc?

I tried that but it doesn't work.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
$.getJSON("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/all",
  {
    tags: "awesome",
    tagmode: "any",
    format: "json"
  },
  function(data) {
    $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
      $("<img/>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo("#flickr-images");
      if ( i == 3 ) return false;
    });
  });
});
})(jQuery);
```